# How do I stabilize a reverse shell in when the attack box is using powershell?

Tags: powershell, reverse-shell

I've managed to get a version of netcat onto my Windows machine and I can run the standard:

```
nc -lvnp 1234
```

and this properly connects to the victim's machine, but it's a very fragile connection. Ctrl + C will just drop the connection, tab doesn't auto-complete, and the up and down arrows don't give me history. On Linux, the common way to stabilize the shell looks like this:

```
python -c "import pty; pty.spawn('/bin/bash')"      //run on victim's machine
CTRL + Z                                            //switches over to your machine
stty raw -echo                                      //run on your machine
fg                                                  //switches back to victim machine
export TERM=xtrm                                    //run on victim machine
```

The problem is that Ctrl + Z just locks up Powershell, so that's about as far as I get. Even if I use a Kali Linux docker container, I am still running that container through Powershell or CMD and I just can't get past that Ctrl + Z issue.

How do I stabilize a reverse shell through Powershell or CMD?

Comment: Ctrl-Z is end-of-file on Windows, equivalent of Ctrl-D in Linux, so I'm not surprised that locks you up.

Answer (score 1):

> it's a very fragile connection. Ctrl + C will just drop the connection, tab doesn't auto complete, and the up and down arrows don't give me history.

It's not fragile. When you type Ctrl+C, the shell sends a SIGINT to the running process, which happens to be `nc`. This causes the process to terminate, breaking the connection. Tab doesn't autocomplete and arrows don't provide history because you aren't using a pty.

> ctrl + z just locks up Powershell so that's about as far as I get.

Once you run that Python command to set up a pty, you can use keys to view history. However, on Windows, Ctrl+Z is EOF (equivalent to Ctrl+D on Linux). On Linux, Ctrl+Z will cause SIGTSTP to be sent to the running process, and it will be detached from the terminal. Because you are running Powershell, when you type Ctrl+Z, it is interpreted by Windows.